# Sharepoint question about UserControl on WebPart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, controls

I added UserControl Webpart on the site and got this error:

error CS0117: 'ASP._60b6ad6d_6998_4413_8d26_f07e4e897ce8_1417418301' does not contain a definition for 'btnPressMe_Click'

It is very simple user control.

Comment: You'll have to give some more detail if you want help.

Comment: You should update the question title to make it more clear what you are asking, and to make the question more search-friendly. Ideally, you want other developers with similar issues to be able to find your question (and its eventual answer) rather than posting their own duplicate question. Also, you should post a relevant snippet of your source code or indicate what troubleshooting steps you've already taken.

Answer (score 3):

Going out on a limb I'd say you have a button in your user control that you double clicked in the visual designer, creating a default event handler for it, and at some point you removed the generated method stub from your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Or, going out on another limb, you have updated the ASCX with your button and replaced it in the 12 hive but did not build and replace the associated DLL in the GAC or Bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but maybe there's an error in the directives of the user control?
See the [Directive Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e%28VS.71%29.aspx) at MSDN

Oh, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4aad8at%28VS.71%29.aspx) is a link to the MSDN page of the Compiler Error CS0117.